# multiprocessing run 2 tasks in parallel - project on Raspberry Pi using Bluepy

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a project whose objective is to connect several nano 33 iot Arduinos (as peripherals) to a Raspberry pi (as the central), using Bluetooth Low Energy.

My Arduinos send data continuously to the Raspberry Pi. I am using the "listen for notifications" feature to intercept all data in real time.

My code looks like this:

```
from bluepy import btle

class MyDelegate(btle.DefaultDelegate):
    def __init__(self,params):
        btle.DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)

    def handleNotification(self,cHandle,data):
        print(data)


def connectionArduino1() :
    global Arduino1
    print("trying to connect to Arduino1")
    connected = False
    while(connected == False) :
        try :
            Arduino1 = btle.Peripheral("xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx")
            Arduino1.setDelegate(MyDelegate(0))

            servicesArduino1=Arduino1.getServices()

            sArduino1 = Arduino1.getServiceByUUID(UUID)
            chArduino1 = sArduino1.getCharacteristics()[0]

            Arduino1.writeCharacteristic(14,bytes('Start','utf-8'))
            Arduino1.writeCharacteristic(chArduino1.valHandle+1, (1).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little'))
            connected = True
        except :
            connected = False


def connectionArduino2() :
    global Arduino2
    print("trying to connect to Arduino2")
    connected = False
    while(connected == False) :
        try :
            Arduino2 = btle.Peripheral("xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx")
            Arduino2.setDelegate(MyDelegate(0))

            servicesArduino2=Arduino2.getServices()

            sArduino2 = Arduino2.getServiceByUUID(UUID)
            chArduino2 = sArduino2.getCharacteristics()[0]

            Arduino2.writeCharacteristic(14,bytes('Start','utf-8'))
            Arduino2.writeCharacteristic(chArduino2.valHandle+1, (1).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little'))
            connected = True
        except :
            connected = False


def mainLoop() :
    while True:

        try :
            if Arduino1.waitForNotifications(5) :
                print("Notification received")
            else :
                try :
                    Arduino1.disconnect()
                    connectionArduino1()
                except :
                    connectionArduino1()
        except :
            connectionArduino1()

        try :
            if Arduino2.waitForNotifications(5) :
                print("Notification received")
            else :
                try :
                    Arduino2.disconnect()
                    connectionArduino2()
                except :
                    connectionArduino2()
        except :
            connectionArduino2()

connectionArduino1()
connectionArduino2()
mainLoop()
```

The `try` commands in the `mainLoop`:

1. Make sure that the program does not crash if one of the Arduinos is disconnected
2. Reconnect the Raspberry Pi automatically to an Arduino if it is disconnected (by launching the `connectionArduinoX` function)

The problem is when one of the two Arduinos is disconnected: while the program tries to reconnect to it, it is no longer able to read the notifications received from the other Arduinos. The `mainLoop` function is therefore paused.

I would like to create a robust program that is able to read all the notifications received by the connected Arduinos and that is able to reconnect to the Arduinos in parallel (if one of them was disconnected) so that the `mainLoop` function is never paused.

I tried to create threads as follows:

```
from bluepy import btle
from threading import Thread

class MyDelegate(btle.DefaultDelegate):
    def __init__(self,params):
        btle.DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)

    def handleNotification(self,cHandle,data):
        print(data)

Arduino1Connected = False
Arduino2Connected = False

def connectionArduino1() :
    global Arduino1
    global Arduino1Connected
    print("trying to connect to Arduino1")
    connected = False
    while(Arduino1Connected == False) :
        try :
            Arduino1 = btle.Peripheral("xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx")
            Arduino1.setDelegate(MyDelegate(0))
            
            servicesArduino1=Arduino1.getServices()
            
            sArduino1 = Arduino1.getServiceByUUID(UUID)
            chArduino1 = sArduino1.getCharacteristics()[0]

            Arduino1.writeCharacteristic(14,bytes('Start','utf-8'))
            Arduino1.writeCharacteristic(chArduino1.valHandle+1, (1).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little'))
            Arduino1Connected = True
        except :
            Arduino1Connected = False
            
            
def connectionArduino2() : 
    global Arduino2
    global Arduino2Connected
    print("trying to connect to Arduino2")
    connected = False
    while(Arduino2Connected == False) :
        try :
            Arduino2 = btle.Peripheral("xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx")
            Arduino2.setDelegate(MyDelegate(0))
            
            servicesArduino2=Arduino2.getServices()
            
            sArduino2 = Arduino2.getServiceByUUID(UUID)
            chArduino2 = sArduino2.getCharacteristics()[0]

            Arduino2.writeCharacteristic(14,bytes('Start','utf-8'))
            Arduino2.writeCharacteristic(chArduino2.valHandle+1, (1).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little'))
            Arduino2Connected = True
        except :
            Arduino2Connected = False
            
            
def mainLoop() : 
    while True:
    
        try : 
            if Arduino1.waitForNotifications(5) :
                print("Notification received")
            else :
                try :
                    Arduino1.disconnect()
                    Arduino1Connected = False
                except :
                    Arduino1Connected = False
        except :
            Arduino1Connected = False

        try : 
            if Arduino2.waitForNotifications(5) :
                print("Notification received")
            else :
                try :
                    Arduino2.disconnect()
                    Arduino2Connected = False
                except :
                    Arduino2Connected = False
        except :
            Arduino2Connected = False

thread1 = Thread(target = mainLoop)
thread2 = Thread(target = connectionArduino1)
thread3 = Thread(target = connectionArduino2)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()
thread3.join()
```

But this doesn't work and I think my code is much slower.

So I thought of using the threading or multiprocessing principle. With a `mainLoop` process that reads all the notifications received from the connected Arduinos, and a process able to detect a possible disconnection of one of the Arduinos and able to reconnect automatically.

Do you know how I can achieve this?

Or do you have other solutions that allow to continuously read all the notifications received by the Arduinos and in parallel detect the disconnections and reconnect directly?

Comment: I think I would create a `Queue` and then start a thread for each Arduino client passing it the queue. The thread then handles its client and reconnections and puts any messages it receives in the queue. The main program can use `select` to wait for messages on either queue, or even simpler, check each queue for messages rather than blocking waiting for messages.

Comment: After several tests, it finally works, thank you for your answer